# Read and write hexa-decimal to decimal?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

How to convert hexadecimal to decimal from file reader in Java?

Like : 12345abcd

Java application should be able to read and write to it. Filereader.

```
1234ABCD 9876FEDC
12345678 ABCDEF12
5678AB01
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Are you stuck on how to read the file, or how to do the hex to decimal conversion?

Comment: I can read the file but i can't convert the hex to decimal from FileReader. i tried int a = Integer.parseInt(b, 16); and for binairy (0b) and 2. but i can't . It is assignment and has a deadline.

Answer (score 1):

The [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class has a method called `toHexString(int i)` that will convert an `int` to a string representing the Hex, and a `valueOf(String s, int radix)` that converts from a String with a radix, which for Hex would be 16.  No sense in reinventing the wheel here.